# Get Dataframe from pandas groupby (pd.grouper)

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, group-by

From the below data, i need to create daywise chunk through iteration

```
 data:
       lable        datetime    value             daytime
    0   tag1  5/30/2022 0:00  361.378 2022-05-30 00:00:00
    1   tag1  5/30/2022 0:01  344.072 2022-05-30 00:01:00
    2   tag1  5/30/2022 0:02  321.001 2022-05-30 00:02:00
    3   tag1  5/30/2022 0:03  296.715 2022-05-30 00:03:00
    4   tag1  5/30/2022 0:04  272.290 2022-05-30 00:04:00
    5   tag1  5/30/2022 0:05  250.708 2022-05-30 00:05:00
    6   tag1  5/31/2022 0:06  283.087 2022-05-31 00:06:00
    7   tag1  5/31/2022 0:07  314.322 2022-05-31 00:07:00
    8   tag1  5/31/2022 0:08  345.811 2022-05-31 00:08:00
    9   tag1  5/31/2022 0:09  362.085 2022-05-31 00:09:00
    10  tag1  5/31/2022 0:10  363.021 2022-05-31 00:10:00
    11  tag1  5/31/2022 0:11  364.575 2022-05-31 00:11:00
    12  tag1  5/31/2022 0:12  361.114 2022-05-31 00:12:00
```

I have used the below code. I am creating a "daytime" column from datetime as i was not able to use the groupby. it was giving type error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'` (when i was trying `data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D'))`

```
data['daytime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.datetime)
data_grp = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='daytime', freq='D'))
```

then to get the daywise chunk, i use the below code

```
for i in data_grp:
    day_chunk = i
    print type(day_chunk)

Output:
(Timestamp('2022-05-30 00:00:00', freq='D'),   lable        datetime    value             daytime
0  tag1  5/30/2022 0:00  361.378 2022-05-30 00:00:00
1  tag1  5/30/2022 0:01  344.072 2022-05-30 00:01:00
2  tag1  5/30/2022 0:02  321.001 2022-05-30 00:02:00
3  tag1  5/30/2022 0:03  296.715 2022-05-30 00:03:00
4  tag1  5/30/2022 0:04  272.290 2022-05-30 00:04:00
5  tag1  5/30/2022 0:05  250.708 2022-05-30 00:05:00)
<type 'tuple'>
(Timestamp('2022-05-31 00:00:00', freq='D'),    lable        datetime    value             daytime
6   tag1  5/31/2022 0:06  283.087 2022-05-31 00:06:00
7   tag1  5/31/2022 0:07  314.322 2022-05-31 00:07:00
8   tag1  5/31/2022 0:08  345.811 2022-05-31 00:08:00
9   tag1  5/31/2022 0:09  362.085 2022-05-31 00:09:00
10  tag1  5/31/2022 0:10  363.021 2022-05-31 00:10:00
11  tag1  5/31/2022 0:11  364.575 2022-05-31 00:11:00
12  tag1  5/31/2022 0:12  361.114 2022-05-31 00:12:00)
<type 'tuple'>
```

I want output as a dataframe and not tuple. can you please tell me how to get the day_chuck as pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
for name, group in data_grp:
    day_chunk = group
```